# How to prove $\displaystyle \int ^\infty_0 \dfrac{e^x}{e^{x^\lambda}}dx $ is divergent when $\lambda>1$

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

The integration is
\begin{equation}
\displaystyle \int ^\infty_0 \dfrac{e^x}{e^{x^\lambda}} dx
\end{equation}

It's not hard for me to prove this integration is divergent when $\lambda$ $\leq 1$. However, I tried to use limit comparison, and I also tried to find a function that is less than it and diverges. I finally ended up getting nothing.  Thus, any help with this? Thanks!

(Btw, on the denominator is $e^{x^\lambda}$. That is $\lambda$ is the exponent of $x$, instead of $(e^x)^\lambda$  )

Comment: This is false [for e.g.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+of+e%5E%28x-x%5E2%29+from+0+to+inf&dataset=) $\lambda=2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the contrary: if $\lambda>1$, your integral converges due to the upper bound $\int_0^2e^xdx+\int_2^\infty e^{-(2^{\lambda-1}-1)x}dx$.